# How to decrypt a file using gpg without knowing its type before encrypting

Tags: gnupg

I know how to decrypt a file:

`gpg --passphrase mySecretPass -o /home/me/dummy.xml -d /home/me/dummy.gpg`

but in my case this `dummy.gpg` can be xml or zip before encryption.

How could I save the output with the proper extension?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the extension before decrypting. You can run:

`gpg --passphrase mySecretPass -o /home/me/dummy -d /home/me/dummy.gpg`

And then run: 
`file /home/me/dummy`

The [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command will return the file type based on the header.
You can also use [`mimetype`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mimetype)

Comment: Thanks! So I have to save it with some dummy name, check the myme type and than change its name.